# PHP Loop through HTML table elements from submit form

Tags: php

I have a jQuery function to dynamically add rows containing input fields, this exists on a form, the function adds text boxes (distinct names)  to each cell in the table

an example of the generated HTML would be:

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2px" margin="0" >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name_1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="surname_1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age_1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name_2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="surname_2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age_2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name_3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="surname_3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age_3"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I am reading the "$_POST['varName'] data with the following code:

```
<?php
    $cnt = 1 ;
    $fName = ( $name ."_" .$cnt) ;
    do {
        echo("$_POST[$fName]  <br>");
        $cnt = $cnt +1 ; 
        $fName = ( $fldName ."_" .$cnt) ;

        } while (isset($_POST[$fName]));
    ?>
```

however, i would like to simply loop through each row in the table and read the data sequentially in a loop (using PHP), my idea is to pass the table object to a php function, is this possible?

Basically i am looking for a solution to read the table data, where each row contains input boxes "name_X", "surname_x" and "age_x" and i will not know how many rows exist at design time... (i will never have more than 9 rows)

Hope this is clear! 
... Any Suggestions?

Comment: You cannot access the HTML table itself from PHP if that's what you're suggesting. Only the form field values get posted to your PHP script.

Comment: Isn't the code that you posted doing exactly what you are asking?

Comment: "my idea is to pass the table object to a php function". The table is not a PHP object, it is HTML which is just markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hidden field and set there the number of rows as value using javascript.
In the php script you can then use a simple for loop.

Simething like this:

```
$rowCount = $_POST['hiddenName'];
for($i=1; i<=$rowCount; $i++)
{

  $_POST['name_'.$i]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great!, the answer above solves the problem in a different way, however i think this is a solution to the current question!. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 4):

i'm pretty sure you must use an array in the name="" values

```
<td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Used both the name array and the simple for loop to find a suitable answer. Thanks All!

HTML: I have a js function that adds the following to a table dynamically (Button on form)

```
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="surname[]" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age[]"> </td>
    </tr>
```

PHP: and this is the way that i process the table within the form

```
<?php  
$rowCount =  count($_POST['name']); 
    echo "<table>";
    for($i=1; $i<=$rowCount; $i++)
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$_POST['name'][$i -1]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$_POST['surname'][$i -1]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$_POST['age'][$i -1]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";?>
```